# Не находит страницу при возврате коллекции из контроллера

Tags: asp.net-core

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Сначала в чем суть моей задачи. С фронта передается ID работ, затем работу по нему ищутся в БД и фильтруются.
Далее идет возврат коллекции в представление.
Теперь в чем проблема. На входе проваливаюсь в IActionResult и получаю свой ID с фронта (все нормально), но когда возвращаю коллекцию на фронт, то пишет, что страница /Details/GetDetails/ не найдена.
Я почти уверен, что проблема в моих HTTP Атрибутах HttpGet и HttpPost, но не могу никак понять что именно не так.
Как посылаю с фронта:

```
var onPressBtnDetails = () => {
var result = "";
var selectedElem = $("#idImages:hover").find("p")[0].textContent;   // Получаем первый подходящий текст для поиска
//var replaceSelectedElem = selectedElem.replace("Описание:", "");
//var sr = replaceSelectedElem.split("\" ")[1];
//var str = sr.split(".");
//$("#idImages:hover").find("p")[0].textContent;   
var strForBack = "";    // В эту переменную будем складывать результат строки и отправим на бэк
// Ищем если в строке есть две кавычки, то будем сплитить строку и возьмем лишь то, что до двойных кавычек
strForBack = selectedElem;
return $.ajax({
    url: '/Details/GetDetails/',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        ID: strForBack
    },
    success: (data) => {
        result = "OK";
        console.log(result);
        //window.location.href = 'https://localhost:44377/Details/Details';   // Для теста
    },
    error: (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        result = "ERROR";
    }
});
```

};

Как обрабатываю на бэке:

```
 List<FileModel> imagePath = new List<FileModel>();
    // Переходим на страницу подробностей  
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetDetails(int id, int i) {
        var data = SearchInDB(id);
        return View("GetDetails", data);  // ПОСЛЕ ЭТОЙ СТРОКИ НЕ НАХОДИТ СТРАНИЦУ /Details/GetDetails/
    }
    // Возвращаемся на главную
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    }
    // Будем искать в БД нужный проект  
    [HttpGet]
    public List<FileModel> SearchInDB(int id) {        
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            con.Open();
            using (var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT p1.ID, p1.TITLE AS TITLE_DETAILS, p1.DETAILS_TASK, p1.IMAGE_PATH " +
                "FROM PortfolioDetails as p1 " +
                "JOIN Portfolio as p2 ON p1.ID_GROUP = p2.ID_GROUP " +
                "WHERE p2.ID_GROUP = " + id, con)) {
                using (var reader = com.ExecuteReader()) {
                    if (reader.HasRows) {
                        while (reader.Read()) {
                            imagePath.Add(new FileModel {
                                ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
                                Title = reader["TITLE_DETAILS"].ToString(),
                                ImagePath = reader["IMAGE_PATH"].ToString(),
                                CommentDetails = reader["DETAILS_TASK"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return imagePath;
    }
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и подсказки!

Comment: return View(data); пробовали так?

Comment: и добавьте тогда (реализацию сами уже)     [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetDetails(int id) {
        List<FileModel> model = new List<FileModel>();
        return View(model);
    }

Comment: C return View(data); попробовал, результат тот же. Не находит /Detils/GetDetails/
Во втором случае коллекция пустая и страница пуста.
Второй метод я оставил как был. А первый записал так:
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetDetails(int id) {
            //var data = SearchInDB(id);
            //return View(data);
            List<FileModel> model = new List<FileModel>();
            return View(model);
        }
Я просто уже перестаю понимать, почему он не определяет id при входе в IActionResult вторым способом. Пробовал и GET запрос передавать с фронта. Результат тот же.